# How Can I Target This <span> in CSS?

Tags: html, css, shopify, shopify-liquid

I'm trying to add a line through style to the 'original' price on a shopify site when the sale/compare at price is used.

I'm a bit stumped at how to target this  for styling. I'm guessing it's something simple, would appreciate the help!

I'm trying to select the  text and style with:

```
text-decoration: line-through !important;
```

See Below HTML

```
<div class="col-span-1">
        <h1 class="text-md">
          THE BLACK PREMIUM SELVEDGE
          <span data-product-price>
            $375.00
          </span>
          <div data-price-wrapper>
            
            <span class="visually-hidden" data-compare-text="">Regular price</span>
            <div data-compare-price="">
               $625.00 
            </div>
```

I've tried all kinds of variations of selectors/nth child etc. and nothing seems to work.

I've only been able to successfully target the col-span-1 and text-md classes.

The span I'm trying to select has

```
data-price-wrapper
```

in it, but as it's not a class or id I'm unsure how to select it!

Comment: You don't have a span with data-price-wrapper in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

P.S. Don't use `!important` because it will hurt you in the long run.

```css
[data-price-wrapper] {
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jakob and Kevin!! That works perfectly. I figured it was something simple to select that 'data-price-wrapper' that I just didn't know. Appreciate the quick help very much.